# Can it is possible to use click event in tag cloud of D3 and If yes how?

Tags: d3.js

d3-cloud About click event  Can it is possible to use click event in tag cloud of D3 and  If yes how

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="../lib/d3/d3.js"></script>
<script src="../d3.layout.cloud.js"></script>
<body>
<script>
  var fill = d3.scale.category20();
  var zz= ["Hello", "world", "normally", "you", "want", "more", "words", "than", "this"];
  d3.layout.cloud().size([300, 300])

      .words((zz).map(function(d) {
        return {text: d, size: 10 + Math.random() * 90};
      }))
      .rotate(function() { return ~~(Math.random() * 2) * 90; })
      .font("Impact")
      .fontSize(function(d) { return d.size; })
      .on("end", draw)
      .start();

  function draw(words) {
    d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", 300)
        .attr("height", 300)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(150,150)")
      .selectAll("text")
        .data(words)
      .enter().append("text")
        .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })
        .style("font-family", "Impact")
        .style("fill", function(d, i) { return fill(i); })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
        })
        .text(function(d) { return d.text; });
  }
</script>
```

( I want "Hello", "world", "normally", "you", "want", "more", "words", "than", "this" words to be clickable)

Comment: The answer to your question is almost certainly yes, but without any explanation what you mean by "tag cloud" (i.e. what implementation, example?) we won't be able to give you any more detail.

Answer (score 8):

Just add the following at the end of your script:

```
...
.text(function(d) { return d.text; })
.on("click", function(d) {
    alert(d.text);
  });
```

Comment: I'm interested in using d3.js for a cluster map. Is it possible to attach or nest anchor tags within the nodes to make them clickable, or would I just use click events to handle them?

Comment: Thanks! I get the event as first arg, and `d` as the second one, so: `.on('click', function(ev, d) { alert(d.text); })` This is with D3 6.3.0, d3-cloud 1.2.5.

Answer (score 3):

you can bind events with .on

I will show you how to enlarge or reduce the tag size when mouse hovering, and to log when clicking a tag (i'm using coffee script)

```
.on("mouseover", ->
  d3.select(this).style("font-size", (d) ->
    d.size + 10 +"px"
  )
.on("mouseout", ->
  d3.select(this).style("font-size", (d) ->
    d.size - 10 +"px"
  )
.on("mousedown",  ->
  console.log(this)
```